# Java - Word - Memory issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code to take screenshot and paste it in a word document.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class WordAutomation {

    public static String projectpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    public static FileOutputStream out;
    public static String ScreenshotPath = projectpath+"\\Screenshots\\";
    public static XWPFDocument docx;
    public static XWPFRun run;
    public static String wordFile;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        docx = new XWPFDocument();
        run = docx.createParagraph().createRun();
        wordFile = ScreenshotPath+"ScreenshotFile.docx";
        out = new FileOutputStream(wordFile);

        run.setText("Test Started");
        run.addBreak();
        //calling screenshot method
        
        run.setText("Its a Pass scenario");
        run.addBreak();
        //calling screenshot method

        run.setText("Its a Fail scenario");
        run.addBreak();
        //calling screenshot method

        run.setText("Test End");
        run.addBreak(); 
        //calling screenshot method

        docx.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        docx.close();
    }
}
```

above code working fine without any issues, but it's facing memory issue when i run this snippet for hours to take screenshots and paste it on word document in selenium automation scripts. So i modified this script like below.

```
run.setText("Test Started");
run.addBreak();
//calling screenshot method
docx.write(out);
out.flush();

run.setText("Test End");
run.addBreak();
//calling screenshot method

docx.write(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
docx.close();
```

Word document was generated and saved without any issues but i couldn't open it, Its showing below error.

[image]

Please help me to solve it.. Thanks in advance